# Make div stick at the bottom even if scroll it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am implementing a footer which should stick at the bottom of the window even if I scroll. And the scroll bar for the content above footer should be within content itself (not extending to footer).

Is there a way of doing this? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: google `fixed footer css`

Comment: @kingkode Please check the picture. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Set CSS for your footer element:

```
.footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: But the content's scroll bar will be blocked by the footer.

Comment: You can show your html code, or create JSFiddle?

Comment: Please check the picture. Thanks.

Comment: browser scrolbar blocked?

Comment: So the scroll bar for the content is blocked by the footer.

Comment: add `margin-bottom` to your content block with value footer height

Comment: But it doesn't solve the problem that the scroll bar extends inside the footer

Answer (score 1):

```
.footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

works mostly fine! BUT, if you really want in to be sticky, you should use for example iScroll (http://iscrolljs.com) With iScroll you have only one area to scroll and headers and footers can't be scrolled!

Answer (score 1):

You have a viewport in which you can draw (layout) your page, and you can't draw outside of it.  The scroll bar is a control/decoration on the window itself, and you can't cover it.

What you *can* do is avoid having a scrollbar on the window, and have one on your main content instead.

Set both the footer and the main content positions, and make the main content scrollable with `overflow: scroll` — that way the scroll bar is attached to the content div instead of the browser window.
The footer won't have the scroll bar next to it then, but there may be reserved space on the right.  That is out of your control — it is up to the browser vendor.

It will look like this (I'm using IDs in place of Classes):

```css
#content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
#footer {
    background: white;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
This is the content area. It will have lots of vertical space so that it can scroll.<br>
<br>
a<br><br>
b<br><br>
c<br><br>
d<br><br>
e<br><br>
f<br><br>
g<br><br>
h<br><br>
i<br><br>
j<br><br>
k<br><br>
l<br><br>
m<br><br>
n<br><br>
o<br><br>
p<br><br>
</div>
<div id="footer">
This is the footer part and may have <em>the fine print</em> and/or navigation links; whatever you like.
</div>
```

... or see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/hpbge7o8/) demonstrating it.